# SQL server Not show Services.msc and SQL Server Services Empty in configuration manager

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2014

After Install SQL server 2014 in windows 10. i am running sql server First connect server database its Woorking. when i connect local database showing  ERROR like this

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

i am trying restart sql service in configuration manager there is no sql services.  another method i have tired  services.msc searching sql server to start there also  sql server not  dispaly .
 please how to fix this issues?

Comment: You have to install full package of SQL Server in you local system. I think now you have management components alone.

Comment: But its working when i conenct server host db working .Not Working local  db when connect its conected

Comment: where i find full package  SQL server to install

Comment: That means server has SQL Server Database service which is not available in your local

Comment: @SankarRaj please where find full package to download sql server 2014

Comment: Here https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=42299 . This link is for Express edition which is free. For other editions, You can purchase at Microsoft website.

Comment: @SankarRaj Close
Choose the download that you want  showing many list  i am using windows 10 64 bit which one i choose

Comment: Express 64BIT\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe this is the one you need.

Comment: @thank you sankar Raj

Comment: glad to help. feel free to ask if you have any other issues regarding this